# Degrees of freedom of this tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gauge-theory, degrees-of-freedom

I would like to know the [degrees of freedom](https://www.quora.com/What-does-degree-of-freedom-of-a-tensor-in-N-dimensions-mean) (dof) of the tensor $f$:

\begin{equation}
f_{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu \xi_\nu+\partial_\nu \xi_\mu
\end{equation}

in 4 dimensions using the common index notation. Naively i would expect it to be 4 since if I choose $\xi$ it reduces the dof by 4 and the tensor $f$ should be completely determined.

On the other hand, in weak GR (gravitational waves), fixing the gauge freedom should reduce the dof of the metric from 10 (symmetric) to  2 (transverse traceless gauge). So would expect the tensor $f$ to have 8 dof.

What is the right number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, there are 4 degrees of freedom.

In General Relativity, 4 more degrees of freedom aren't dynamical, because they enter the Lagrangian without time derivatives.

The best way to show that the correct number of d.o.f. is 2 is to use the ADM (Hamiltonian) formalism for GR. In ADM we:

1. Exclude the non-dynamical degrees of freedom (Lagrangian multipliers) which leaves 6 dynamical d.o.f. arranged as the ADM spatial slice (3D) metric (aka the 1st fundamental form).
2. Apply 4 constraints arising from the 4 gauge transformations that you described. This leaves us with the total of 2 d.o.f.

Comment: What do you mean by "4 more degrees of freedom aren't dynamical, because they enter the Lagrangian without time derivatives."?

Comment: @MrPuh Take 10 components of the metric and the ADM Lagrangian. I claim that $\mathcal{L}$ depends on the time derivatives of only 6 components out of 10. The remaining 4 are thus not dynamical, meaning that the equations of motion for them (Euler-Lagrange equations) are algebraic, not differential.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that given the tensor,

$$f_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu \xi_\nu + \partial_\nu \xi_\mu$$

if we specify the vector $\xi^\mu$, then $f_{\mu\nu}$ is completely determined. Providing there are no constraints on the vector $\xi^\mu$ which could be used to recover one or more components from another, then the degrees of freedom in $d$-dimensional space of $f_{\mu\nu}$ is $d$.